# how to change Apexchart pie chart after select event?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, open-source, vaadin-flow, apexcharts

I am using vaadin 24.3.3 with springboot 3.2.1, and I am using Apexchart.js add-ons 24.0.0, my series and labels are changed based on selection filter by, when select first choice, the labels and series will be something, when select the second choice the labels and series will be something else. **The problem is** whatever choice I select after construct the chart, it is not changed!
this is my code

PieChart.java

```
import com.github.appreciated.apexcharts.ApexChartsBuilder;
import com.github.appreciated.apexcharts.config.builder.ChartBuilder;
import com.github.appreciated.apexcharts.config.builder.LegendBuilder;
import com.github.appreciated.apexcharts.config.builder.ResponsiveBuilder;
import com.github.appreciated.apexcharts.config.chart.Type;
import com.github.appreciated.apexcharts.config.legend.Position;
import com.github.appreciated.apexcharts.config.responsive.builder.OptionsBuilder;

public class PieChart extends ApexChartsBuilder {

    private ApexChartsBuilder apexChartsBuilder;
    String[] colors = {"#a7be54","#4a9342", "#be7e54"};
    private double[] series;

    public PieChart(){
        apexChartsBuilder = new ApexChartsBuilder();
    }

    public void init() {

        apexChartsBuilder = withChart(ChartBuilder.get().withType(Type.PIE).build())
                .withLegend(LegendBuilder.get()
                        .withPosition(Position.BOTTOM)
                        .build())
                .withColors(colors)
                .withResponsive(ResponsiveBuilder.get()
                        .withOptions(OptionsBuilder.get()
                                .withLegend(LegendBuilder.get().withPosition(Position.BOTTOM).build())
                                .build())
                        .build());
    }



    public ApexChartsBuilder getApexChartsBuilder() {
        return apexChartsBuilder;
    }

    public void setApexChartsBuilder(ApexChartsBuilder apexChartsBuilder) {
        this.apexChartsBuilder = apexChartsBuilder;
    }
}
```

DashboardView.java

```
public class DashboardView extends VerticalLayout {

    private final LogService logService;

    private PieChart pieChart;
    private VerticalLayout chartContainer = new VerticalLayout();
    private Select<String> filterBySelection = new Select<>();

    private static final String FILTER_BY_STATUS_CODE = "Status Code";
    private static final String FILTER_BY_DECISIONS = "Decisions";


    public DashboardView(LogService logService) {
        this.logService = logService;
        setSizeFull();
        initChart();
        filterByStatusCode();
        chartContainer.add(pieChart.build());
        chartContainer.setHeight("25%");
        chartContainer.setWidth("50%");
        getStyle().set("overflow", "auto");
        setSizeUndefined();
        prepareSelection();
        add(chartContainer,filterBySelection);
    }

    private void initChart(){
        pieChart = new PieChart();
        pieChart.init();
        pieChart.build().setHeight("25%");
    }


    public void filterByStatusCode(){
        pieChart.withLabels(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()), String.valueOf(HttpStatus.OK.value()));
        pieChart.withSeries(logService.numberOfBadRequestLog(), logService.numberOfSuccessfulRequestLog());
    }




    public void filterByDecisions(){
        pieChart = new PieChart();
        pieChart.init();
        pieChart.withLabels("rewrite", "continue", "stop");
        pieChart.withSeries(256.5,
                52.4,
                69.4);
    }

    private void prepareSelection(){
        filterBySelection.setLabel("Filter By");
        filterBySelection.setItems(FILTER_BY_STATUS_CODE, FILTER_BY_DECISIONS);
        filterBySelection.setValue(FILTER_BY_STATUS_CODE);
        filterBySelection.addValueChangeListener(it -> {
           if (it.getValue().equals(FILTER_BY_STATUS_CODE)){
               filterByStatusCode();
           } else if (it.getValue().equals(FILTER_BY_DECISIONS)){
               filterByDecisions();
           }
        });
    }


}
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: I can't run your vaadin app but from a javascript analogy, I'd guess the problem is that all you do to change the chart is to reassign `pieChart = new PieChart()`. This is unlikely to remove the existing chart; in javascript you'd have to call first `pieChart.destroy()` (if `pieChart` is initialized), but I don't seem to find `destroy` in the java wrapper.  But I'd recommend you initialize `pieChart` only once, then use the update functions [`pieChart.updateSeries`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateSeries), `pieChart.toggleSeries`, `pieChart.showSeries`, `pieChart.hideSeries`, etc.